# Do we need to worry about 32bit or 64bit integers or are we fine just using 'int'

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, cocos2d-x, game-engine

I am using cocos2d-x to make a game and when using "int" in our games do we have to worry about using int32_t and int64_t for 32 and 64 systems, or does just declaring for instance say “int score = 0;” take care of all of that under the hood ?

Comment: I don't know about java or objective C, but in C++ `int` is guaranteed to be 16 bits wide, but on almost all real-world systems the compilers guarantee at least 32 bits ([further reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)).  If you need 64, use `int64_t`.

Comment: A Java `int` is always 32 bits, and a `long` is 64bit. A C/C++ `int` is *usually* 32bit, and a `long` may be either 32bit or 64bit depending on compiler.

Comment: In other words,  Yes, you _do_ have to worry.  Or at least be aware...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C compiling older source code that declared int variables, then using them in statements, like NSLog statements will result in warnings that implicit casting of int to long is not recommended.  It's a warning, so, if you don't mind having a lot of yellow flags in your code, you'll probably be OK.  But, to get rid of the warnings, you have to explicitly cast them to long (long)score, instead of just 'score'.